# viewController management programmatically

Tags: objective-c, navigation, viewcontroller

I have a problem about viewController. I created a program What is viewController based applicaiton. There is 4 button on mainViewController. I used this code for calling mainviewController

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{   

 self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;  
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Then click to any button on homePage , I go to the other viewController. This code for call another viewController belong

```
-(IBAction)clickCalendarButton{
    calendarButton.selected=YES;
    [calendarButton
     setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"afvalkalender_pressed.png"] forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted+UIControlStateSelected)];
    GarbageCalendar *garbageCalendar = [[GarbageCalendar alloc] initWithNibName:@"GarbageCalendar" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:garbageCalendar  animated:YES];
}
```

And then I want to go home page from another viewController. But I didn' go home page viewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create button on detail view controller, which calls something like this:

```
- (IBAction)goBack {
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Yes I goto home page WhenI use this method . But I see problem. I use AKAccordionKit framework. Maybe you know. I created accordion menu on detail view controller. I clicked to home page button I goto the home page but accordion menu viewControllers didn't remove

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what you have to do, but seems that there should be way to remove accordion menu before calling `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your current UI design, based on modal view controllers, then I think you should ensure that your other view controllers have got a button that does the dismiss of the view. Say, e.g., a "Back" or "Done" button. When you click on that button, a delegate method is called that executes: `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Look also at [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) for more info, section "Dismissing a Modal View Controller".

If you would like to consider alternative approaches to your UI, you could look into using a `UINavigationController`, which would make your life a little bit easier with navigating back from one controller to another.